# Get resource SKU to find resource price in GCP (go)

Tags: go, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-billing

I'm trying to figure out a way when given a resource to determine it's SKU so I can look up it's pricing information.

```golang
package main

import (
    "context"
    billingpb "google.golang.org/genproto/googleapis/cloud/billing/v1"
    billing "cloud.google.com/go/billing/apiv1"
)

func main() {
    
    ctx := context.Background()
    client, err := billing.NewCloudCatalogClient(ctx)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }
    req := billingpb.ListSkusRequest{
        Parent: "services/<SKU>",
    }
    result := client.ListSkus(ctx, &req)

    // ... handle result
    
}
```

If for example we examine a `compute.Disk` there isn't any information about it's SKU, only it's type (`pd-ssd`, `pd-standard`).

```golang
    computepb "google.golang.org/genproto/googleapis/cloud/compute/v1"
    
    computepb.Disk{
        CreationTimestamp:           nil,
        Description:                 nil,
        DiskEncryptionKey:           nil,
        GuestOsFeatures:             nil,
        Id:                          nil,
        Kind:                        nil,
        LabelFingerprint:            nil,
        Labels:                      nil,
        LastAttachTimestamp:         nil,
        LastDetachTimestamp:         nil,
        LicenseCodes:                nil,
        Licenses:                    nil,
        LocationHint:                nil,
        Name:                        nil,
        Options:                     nil,
        PhysicalBlockSizeBytes:      nil,
        ProvisionedIops:             nil,
        Region:                      nil,
        ReplicaZones:                nil,
        ResourcePolicies:            nil,
        SatisfiesPzs:                nil,
        SelfLink:                    nil,
        SizeGb:                      nil,
        SourceDisk:                  nil,
        SourceDiskId:                nil,
        SourceImage:                 nil,
        SourceImageEncryptionKey:    nil,
        SourceImageId:               nil,
        SourceSnapshot:              nil,
        SourceSnapshotEncryptionKey: nil,
        SourceSnapshotId:            nil,
        SourceStorageObject:         nil,
        Status:                      nil,
        Type:                        nil,
        Users:                       nil,
        Zone:                        nil,
    }
```

Comment: Another possible way of viewing SKUs is through the console. This [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/billing/docs/how-to/pricing-table#accessing_the_report) has the detailed information on getting resource SKU information from the console.([source](https://cloud.google.com/billing/docs/how-to/cost-table))

Answer (score 1):

`result := client.ListSkus(ctx, &req)`

*result* will be a [*SkuInterator](https://pkg.go.dev/cloud.google.com/go/billing/apiv1#SkuIterator)

```
type SkuIterator struct {
    items    []*billingpb.Sku
    pageInfo *iterator.PageInfo
    nextFunc func() error

    Response interface{}

    InternalFetch func(pageSize int, pageToken string) (results []*billingpb.Sku, nextPageToken string, err error)
}
```

where *SkuIterator.Response* will be type [ListSkusResponse](https://pkg.go.dev/google.golang.org/genproto/googleapis/cloud/billing/v1#ListSkusResponse)

```
type ListSkusResponse struct {
    state         protoimpl.MessageState
    sizeCache     protoimpl.SizeCache
    unknownFields protoimpl.UnknownFields

    Skus []*Sku `protobuf:"bytes,1,rep,name=skus,proto3" json:"skus,omitempty"`
    
    NextPageToken string `protobuf:"bytes,2,opt,name=next_page_token,json=nextPageToken,proto3" json:"next_page_token,omitempty"`
}
```

which has field `Skus` which is an array of [Sku](https://pkg.go.dev/google.golang.org/genproto/googleapis/cloud/billing/v1#Sku)

```
type Sku struct {
    state         protoimpl.MessageState
    sizeCache     protoimpl.SizeCache
    unknownFields protoimpl.UnknownFields

    Name string `protobuf:"bytes,1,opt,name=name,proto3" json:"name,omitempty"`

    SkuId string `protobuf:"bytes,2,opt,name=sku_id,json=skuId,proto3" json:"sku_id,omitempty"`

    Description string `protobuf:"bytes,3,opt,name=description,proto3" json:"description,omitempty"`

    Category *Category `protobuf:"bytes,4,opt,name=category,proto3" json:"category,omitempty"`
https://cloud.google.com/about/locations/
    
ServiceRegions []string `protobuf:"bytes,5,rep,name=service_regions,json=serviceRegions,proto3" json:"service_regions,omitempty"`

    PricingInfo []*PricingInfo `protobuf:"bytes,6,rep,name=pricing_info,json=pricingInfo,proto3" json:"pricing_info,omitempty"`

    ServiceProviderName string `protobuf:"bytes,7,opt,name=service_provider_name,json=serviceProviderName,proto3" json:"service_provider_name,omitempty"`
}
```

where *Sku.PricingInfo* is an array of [PricingInfo](https://pkg.go.dev/google.golang.org/genproto/googleapis/cloud/billing/v1#PricingInfo)

```
type PricingInfo struct {
    state         protoimpl.MessageState
    sizeCache     protoimpl.SizeCache
    unknownFields protoimpl.UnknownFields

    EffectiveTime *timestamppb.Timestamp `protobuf:"bytes,1,opt,name=effective_time,json=effectiveTime,proto3" json:"effective_time,omitempty"`

    Summary string `protobuf:"bytes,2,opt,name=summary,proto3" json:"summary,omitempty"`

    PricingExpression *PricingExpression `protobuf:"bytes,3,opt,name=pricing_expression,json=pricingExpression,proto3" json:"pricing_expression,omitempty"`

    AggregationInfo *AggregationInfo `protobuf:"bytes,4,opt,name=aggregation_info,json=aggregationInfo,proto3" json:"aggregation_info,omitempty"`

    CurrencyConversionRate float64 `protobuf:"fixed64,5,opt,name=currency_conversion_rate,json=currencyConversionRate,proto3" json:"currency_conversion_rate,omitempty"`
}
```

which should give you the info you want.